# SQl query to pull data from one column into 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a data in the table in 1 column with Sectors and countries ..I need to pull sectors in one column and countries in another..Here is the sample data ..Any help is highly appreciated

```
TYPE    DATA

SECTOR IT
SECTOR Retail   `` 
SECTOR MF`
SECTOR us
region eUROPE
region ASIA
```

Convert into

```
Type DataSector   DataCountry
Sector IT         null
Sector Retail     null
sector MF         null
region  null           Us
region null       asia
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  Type, 
        DataSector  = case when Type = 'SECTOR' THEN Data END, 
        DataCountry = case when Type = 'REGION' THEN Data END
FROM    The_Table
```